# How to replace text in multiple xml files in Linux

Tags: linux, xml, bash, sed, replace

I have below xml header :

```
<wechselkurse xmlns:xsi="https://www.bnd-rates.ezv.admin.ch/monthly" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.bnd-rates.ezv.admin.ch/monthlyrates.xsd">
```

And i want to replace header in multiple xml files with :

```
<wechselkurse xmlns="http://www.ps.ezv.admin.ch/apps/rates" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ps.ezv.admin.ch/apps/rates/monthlyrates.xsd">
```

I tried below find command , the command didnt throw an error but it didnt even worked:

```
sed -i "s#<wechselkurse xmlns:xsi="https://www.bnd-rates.ezv.admin.ch/monthly" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.bnd-rates.ezv.admin.ch/monthlyrates.xsd">#<wechselkurse xmlns="http://www.ps.ezv.admin.ch/apps/rates" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ps.ezv.admin.ch/apps/rates/monthlyrates.xsd">#" *.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the replacement in your sed command uses double quotes, you should surround the command with single quotes.

```
sed -i 's#<wechselkurse xmlns:xsi="https://www.bnd-rates.ezv.admin.ch/monthly" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.bnd-rates.ezv.admin.ch/monthlyrates.xsd">#<wechselkurse xmlns="http://www.ps.ezv.admin.ch/apps/rates" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ps.ezv.admin.ch/apps/rates/monthlyrates.xsd">#' *.xml
```

Comment: But do note that if you're doing this on hundreds of files then you need to check each one, because the slightest variation in format (for example a newline instead of a space) will cause this to fail. Use of regular expressions with XML is very error-prone and fragile; it's much more robust to use an XML-specific tool such as XSLT or XQuery.